# WildFly expression variables

Tags: configuration, jboss, wildfly, java-ee-8

Is there any complete list of variables supported in WildFly web configuration expressions (eg rewrite filters)? Like %U, %h, %p...

```
<filters>
<rewrite name="http-to-https" redirect="true" target="https://myhostname:8443%U"/>
</filters>

<server name="default-server">
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
        ...
        <filter-ref name="http-to-https" predicate="equals(%p,8080)"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current WildFly (15) uses Undertow 2.0 so take a look at Undertow documentation on predicates:
http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-2.0.0/predicates-attributes-handlers.html

Answer (score 1):

These are the attributes used by `AccessLogHandler.java` for log.

**%a** - Remote IP address

**%A** - Local IP address

**%b** - Bytes sent, excluding HTTP headers, or '-' if no bytes
 were sent

**%B** - Bytes sent, excluding HTTP headers

**%h** - Remote host name

**%H** - Request protocol

**%l** - Remote logical username from identd (always returns '-')

**%m** - Request method

**%p** - Local port

**%q** - Query string (excluding the '?' character)

**%r** - First line of the request

**%s** - HTTP status code of the response

**%t** - Date and time, in Common Log Format format

**%u** - Remote user that was authenticated

**%U** - Requested URL path

**%v** - Local server name

**%D** - Time taken to process the request, in millis

**%T** - Time taken to process the request, in seconds

**%I** - current Request thread name (can compare later with stacktraces)

In addition, the caller can specify one of the following aliases for
 commonly utilized patterns:

- **common** - `%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b`

  **combined** -
   `%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b "%{i,Referer}" "%{i,User-Agent}"`

There is also support to write information from the cookie, incoming
 header, or the session
 It is modeled after the apache syntax:

- `%{i,xxx}` for incoming headers

  `%{o,xxx}` for outgoing response headers

  `%{c,xxx}` for a specific cookie

  `%{r,xxx}` xxx is an attribute in the ServletRequest

  `%{s,xxx}` xxx is an attribute in the HttpSession

Comment: Hey if in my operations instradamento of equal i wanna do like or contains? Because I wanna add a list of allowed host